# Funcion Ajax Fetch

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, fetch

Hola lo que estoy intentado hacer es que al darle *click* al botón *Modificar* me ejecute la petición *Fecth*.

Pero es que nunca entra debería decirme `alert('Entraste!!')` pero se queda sin hacer nada.

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

He probado con *addEventListener* y nada, la única forma de que haga algo el botón es añadiendo el *action* al *form* y quitandole el `type="button"`, casi el mismo código en mi login y funciona. no se porque en este no.

Debería ser simple darle *click* al botón y que ejecute el *Fetch* y me traiga una respuesta del servidor.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
       <div class="form-group">
           <form class="form">
            <h1>Edición</h1>
            <p>Modifica los Datos del Usuario {{data.nombre}}</p>
            <hr>
            <label><b>Nombre</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" value="{{data.nombre}}" autocomplete="off" required>
            
            <label><b>Email</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email"  id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="{{data.email}}" autocomplete="off" required>

            <label><b>Cargo</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="role" placeholder="Cargo" name="role" value="{{data.role}}" autocomplete="off" required>
             
            <hr>
            <button id="boton-mod" type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar</button>
            
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
   
    $("#boton-mod").on('click',function() {
    alert('Entraste!!')
    alert(data);
    
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    let role = $("#role").val();

    fetch(`/modificar/${data.id}`,{
      method:'POST', 
      headers:{'Content-type': 'application/json'}, 
      body: JSON.stringify({nombre:nombre,email:email, role:role})
      }).then(res=> res.text())
        .then(data=>{
            alert(data);
        });

    });
     </script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rykzu12f/ si tira el alert, estas seguro de que has incluido la libreria de JQUERY?

Comment: Un detalle adicional. Lo veo dentro de un elemento *form* y le asignas type="reset" esto tiene efecto, y no veo event.preventdefault de modo que va a afectar al form. Lee [Button type attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type)

Comment: Hola Le quite el type="reset" eso fue un error el e.preventdefault tambien lo agregue y no funciona.  tengo en mi header los links de JQUERY

Comment: Edité la pregunta para poner un fragmento de código ejecutable y funciona correctamente, fallando en `alert(data);` porque _data_ no está definido.

Comment: Hola lo pude solucionar gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="form">
           <form id="form" class="form-group" action="/modificar/{{data.id}}">
            <h1>Edición</h1>
            <p>Modifica los Datos del Usuario {{data.nombre}}</p>
            <hr>
            <label><b>Nombre</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" value="{{data.nombre}}" autocomplete="off" required>
            
            <label><b>Email</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email"  id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="{{data.email}}" autocomplete="off" required>

            <label><b>Cargo</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="role" placeholder="Cargo" name="role" value="{{data.role}}" autocomplete="off" required>
             
            <hr>
            <button id="boton-mod" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar</button>  
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
   
    $("#boton-mod").on('click',function(e) {
   
    e.preventDefault();

    let email = $("#email").val();
    let nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    let role = $("#role").val();

    fetch($("#form").attr('action'),{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{'Content-type': 'application/json'}, 
        body: JSON.stringify({nombre:nombre,email:email, role:role})
        
        }).then(res => res.text())
          .then(data =>{
              if(data==="Success"){
  
             Swal.fire({
                    icon: "success",
                    html:'<span style="background:white color:black"><strong>Conectado Con Exito!</strong><span>',
                    timer:1000,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
            
                onClose: () => {
                window.location = "dashboard";
                }
        });
      }
    })
});
     </script>
```